# Encountering "Connection refused" and Handshake Error in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, localhost

**Description:**

I'm facing a problem in my Flutter application, and I'm seeing the following errors:

1. > "Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 57536." This error occurs when trying to connect to the URI "https://localhost:7110/api/Warehouse/GetAllWarehouseLabelDto."
2. After attempting to replace "localhost" with "10.0.2.2" in the URI, a new error occurred:

   > D/EGL_emulation(31284): app_time_stats: avg=892.41ms min=58.76ms max=1726.07ms count=2
   > E/flutter (31284): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
   > E/flutter (31284): #0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:99:46)
   > E/flutter (31284): #1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:142:25)
   > E/flutter (31284): #2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:918:54)
   > E/flutter (31284): #3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1047:19)
   > E/flutter (31284):

**Details:**

1. The first error seems to be related to a socket connection issue, with the URI "https://localhost:7110/api/Warehouse/GetAllWarehouseLabelDto."
2. The second error occurred after replacing "localhost" with "10.0.2.2" and is a handshake error with the message "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate."

**Question:**

What could be the potential reasons for the "Connection refused" error, and how can I resolve it? Additionally, how can I address the handshake error and handle certificate verification failures in Flutter/Dart? Any guidance on troubleshooting these issues would be greatly appreciated.